# IsModified is always false on entry's collection after modifying

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a many-to-many relationship set up with Entity Framework like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method where you can modify the Courses that a Student is enrolled in, by both removing and adding StudentCourses for the Student.

One thing I want to do is check if the StudentCourses collection was modified for the Student. I'm trying to do this by using the IsModified property on the Student entry.

```
public async Task<Student> EditStudentAsync(int id)
{
    var existingStudent = await _dbContext.Students
            .Include(s => s.StudentCourses)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id.Equals(id));

    existingStudent.StudentCourses.RemoveAll(sc => 
        ...
        // courses to delete
    );
    existingStudent.StudentCourses.AddRange(
        ...
        // courses to add
    );

    // check if StudentCourses have been added to or deleted from
    bool coursesChanged = _dbContext.Entry(existingStudent)
                              .Collection(s => s.StudentCourses).IsModified;
    coursesChanged = _dbContext.Entry(existingStudent)
                         .Navigation("StudentCourses").IsModified;
    // do something if they changed

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return existingStudent;
}
```

But it's always coming back as false even when I've added to or removed from the collection. I've tried doing this two different ways, with Collection and Navigation on the Student entry, and neither one works.

Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: What exact EF Core version are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev - EF Core 2.1

Comment: Hmm, looks like `Remove`s are not setting `IsModified`. Additions do set it though. Probably a bug.

Comment: Looks like correct behavior to me.  Nothing has been modified here.  You are deleting and adding items, not modifying.

Comment: @Brad That's true for entity entry. But not for the *collection* entry - the collection *is* modified when you add/remove/update items.

Comment: Why is EditStudentAsync(Guid id) taking a Guid when the Id in your database is int?

Comment: @KirstenGreed - just a mistype, this isn't my actual code, just an easy example and representation of the relationships in my code

Comment: @IvanStoev - I think you may be right, seems like a bug or an oversight. Even though we're adding/removing items from the collection, the collection is modified on that object, so it should be marked as Modified